# How to write an array of tags with using Junit5 and Java in autotest?

Tags: java, tags, junit5

I can't use an array of tags in annotation @Tags using Junit5 and Java.

I try to use next examples from documentation of Junit5 and Java:
@Tags(@Tag("PROD"), @Tag("DEV"))
@Tags(Tag("PROD"), Tag("DEV"))
But it doesn't work.
If I try to use next example, it work.
@Tag("PROD")
@Tag("DEV")

Why I can't to use an array of tags? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `@Tags({ @Tag("PROD"), @Tag("DEV") })`?

Comment: No, it's still not working, it should be a construction as -

public @interface Tags {
    Tag[] value();
}

Comment: This is strange, but suddenly this example @Tags({ @Tag("PROD"), @Tag("DEV") }) has worked ... Plus invalidate cashe and restart IDEA may be help ... Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Tags({ @Tag("PROD"), @Tag("DEV") })